# Converting column values (rows) to columns and aggregate count on two rows of two different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables

1. Program
2. Student

**Student**:

```
Name    Status1   Syear SCode
--------------------
kk       A       2000 1
ra       A       2001  2
Paras    L       2000  2
Prit     L       2001  2
Poot     A       2002  4
```

**Program**:

```
PName       PCode
--------------------
Msc          1
DC           2
PO           4
```

Join on ID

Required output :

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
     (SELECT  
         Program.PName AS v, Status1
      FROM 
         Student, Program  
      WHERE 
         Student.PCode = SCode
      GROUP BY  
         Program.PName, Student.Syear, Status1) AS src
pivot
(
  count(v)
  FOR Status1 IN ([A],)
) as piv
```

It does not display `PNAME` in output

```
          A  L
        -----------
          1  0
          1  2
          1  0
```

Desired output

```
    PNAME  A  L
    -----------
    Msc   1  0
    DC    1  2
    PO    1  0
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Thanks :) I will take care in future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. STATIC PIVOT**

You can do this if the column names is known in advance

```
SELECT PName,ISNULL([A],0) [A],ISNULL([L],0)[L] FROM 
 (
    -- Source data for pivoting
    SELECT P.PName,Status1,
    COUNT(Status1)OVER(PARTITION BY PNAME,Status1)CNT
    FROM #PROGRAM P
    JOIN #Student S ON P.PCODE=S.SCODE
 ) x
 PIVOT 
 (
     --Defines the values in each dynamic columns
     MIN(CNT)
     -- Get the names of columns to pivot
     FOR Status1 IN ([A],[L])
) p            
ORDER BY PName
```

- **[Click here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/283680/replace-null-with-zero-in-static-pivot) to view result**

**2. DYNAMIC PIVOT**

Dynamic pivoting can be done if the number of columns is not known in advance.

First of all get columns dynamically to pivot

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR (MAX)

SELECT @cols = COALESCE (@cols + ',[' + Status1 + ']', '[' + Status1 + ']')
               FROM    (SELECT DISTINCT Status1 FROM #Student) PV 
               ORDER BY Status1
```

Now the below variable is used to replace `NULL` with zero.

```
 DECLARE @NulltoZeroCols NVARCHAR (MAX)

SELECT @NullToZeroCols = SUBSTRING((SELECT ',ISNULL(['+Status1+'],0) AS ['+Status1+']' 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Status1 FROM #Student)TAB  
ORDER BY Status1 FOR XML PATH('')),2,8000)
```

Now pivot it. I have written the logic inside

```
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @query = '-- This outer query forms your pivoted result
             SELECT PName,'+@NullToZeroCols+' FROM 
             (
                -- Source data for pivoting
                SELECT P.PName,Status1,
                COUNT(Status1)OVER(PARTITION BY PNAME,Status1)CNT
                FROM #PROGRAM P
                JOIN #Student S ON P.PCODE=S.SCODE
             ) x
             PIVOT 
             (
                 --Defines the values in each dynamic columns
                 MIN(CNT)
                 -- Get the names from the @cols variable to show as column
                 FOR Status1 IN (' + @cols + ')
            ) p            
            ORDER BY PName;' 

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @query
```

- **[Click here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/283679/replace-null-with-zero-in-dynamic-pivot) to view result**

Comment: I have added code for static as well as dynamic pivot @kanwar kakkar

Comment: I did not get the desired results in my table.

Comment: I have just replaced count() instead of min()
Now I am getting my answers.

Comment: Done thanx.. I will ask for help again.. I am new in sql :D

Comment: Welcome. Sure :) @kanwar kakkar